# zoom leaflet according to circle size in it

Tags: java, android, leaflet

I created an app that uses `Leaflet` in it.

In the screen where the map is, there is also a `progressBar` where I allow uses to search in a specific radius.

The moment they change the value in the progressBar, it changes the size of the circle marker inside the map.

I had like that my map will change its zoom to fit that circle in it.

My code for loading the map is:

```
    String Map_HTML = "<html>\n" +
            "<head>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n" +
            "    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\" href=\"docs/images/favicon.ico\" />\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css\" integrity=\"sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==\" crossorigin=\"\"/>\n" +
            "    <script src=\"https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js\" integrity=\"sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg==\" crossorigin=\"\"></script>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<style>\n" +
            "body {\n" +
            "padding: 0;\n" +
            "margin: 0;\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "html, body, #map {\n" +
            "height: 100%;\n" +
            "width: 100%;\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "</style>\n" +
            "</head>\n" +
            "<body>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<div id=\"mapid\" style=\"width: " + dpWidth + "px; height: " + dpHeight * 0.3 + "px;\"></div>\n" +
            "<script>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "var mymap = L.map('mapid',{zoomControl: false}).setView([" + Lat + ", " + Lon + "], 10);\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {\n" +
            "    minZoom: 7,\n" +
            "    maxZoom: 17,\n" +
            "    attribution: '&copy; <a href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' \n" +
            "    }).addTo(mymap);\n" +
            "\n" +
            "mymap.attributionControl.setPosition('topleft')\n" +
            "L.control.zoom({\n" +
            "position: 'bottomright'\n" +
            "}).addTo(mymap);\n" +
            "L.marker([" + Lat + ", " + Lon + "]).addTo(mymap)\n" +
            "    .bindPopup(\"<b>My Location</b>\").openPopup();\n" +
            "\n" +
            "L.circle([" + Lat + ", " + Lon + "], " + Radius + ", {\n" +
            "    color: 'red',\n" +
            "    fillColor: '#8275FE',\n" +
            "    fillOpacity: 0.4,\n" +
            "    weight: '0'\n" +
            "}).addTo(mymap);\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "var popup = L.popup();\n" +
            "\n" +
            "</script>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "</body>\n" +
            "</html>";
```

where `Radius` is a parameter I insert based on the value of the `progressBar`.

Right now it always initializes the map with zoom: 10 because I don't know how to change it dynamically as I want.

Any way to do so?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the map can fit to the bounds of the circle with `mymap.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());`.

Change your code to:

```
"var circle = L.circle([" + Lat + ", " + Lon + "], " + Radius + ", {\n" +
            "    color: 'red',\n" +
            "    fillColor: '#8275FE',\n" +
            "    fillOpacity: 0.4,\n" +
            "    weight: '0'\n" +
            "}).addTo(mymap);\n" +
            "mymap.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());\n" +
```